# Visual Studio 2005/2008 Add-In

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005, add-in

I am writing a plug for Visual Studio 2005/2008. I want gain access the controls in the following picture:[alt text http://img145.imageshack.us/img145/2773/82813838.jpg](http://img145.imageshack.us/img145/2773/82813838.jpg)

How do it ?

Comment: So, you want to control the auto-complete list? Some pictures actually aren't worth 1,000 words. What are you trying to do?

Comment: you mean you want to implement a context menu?

Comment: I want to create a simple IntelliSense for Prototype(JavaScript Framework).

Comment: Doesn't that just involve writing the "vsdoc" file (with the extra intellisense comments) to go alongside the actual code file? i.e. foo.js and foo.vsdoc.js?

Comment: The problem is not the Intellisense. I want to use this control.

Comment: I can see there's much confusion about what you want to do. Please explain a bit more what do you actually want to achieve. It's more likely that you'll get an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Intellisense in Visual Studio 2008 also works for javascript source code. You don't need an extra add-in for that but rather just documentation file for your javascript. It will also work for Prototype library but you won't have any documentation nor will it work in chaining multiple functions, because it doesn't know return types.

Anyway, this should be a nice start (since it's for 1.6.0 RC1 version):
[Prototype VS2008 Intellisense](http://gatekeeper.opensourceconnections.com/amplify/browser/amplify.js/trunk/javascripts/prototype.intellisense.js?rev=249)